# Deploying ssis 2012 with visual studio 2010

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I've created a new SSIS package in Visual Studio 2010 and started deploying the package to a SQL 2012 database on a remote server.

I can connect to the DB and see the SSISDB folder but when i deploy the package I get the following error:

"The path for 'ISServerExec.exe' cannot be found. The operation will now exit."

Comment: bit of the problem is discribed here: http://thinknook.com/ssis-2012-features-and-the-project-deployment-model-2012-04-08/ this looks like you can't deploy with the new feature, but you should be able to deploy with by righ clicking a folder in integration services and click "import package"

Comment: Your SSIS project is using the new project deployment model, yes? The target server has had the proper SSISDB catalog built out, yes? How are you performing the deploy? Are you right-clicking the project and performing deploy, double clicking the .ispac file to launch the wizard, importing from the SSISDB catalog on the remote server, some other option I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have SSIS 2012 installed on that machine? and the service is running? (check SQL Server Configuration Manager)

This looks like you created an SSIS catalog on a SQL Server machine that has no SSIS service running (or SQL is unable to see the correct version of SSIS running). You will be able to see the catalog and even go through the deployment wizard from visual studio, but will receive the error message you mentioned above when you finalize your deployment.